# Prevent angular from running diggest cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble with angular running diggest cycle on data change. I am using isotope to display some images and messages and when irrelevant data is changed the view gets updated and isotope moves messages. Can I prevent diggest cycle from running when data is updated?

I would want to first check if data updated was relevant to displaying before running diggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can stop it completely, but you can listen and intercept the `$digest` calls.

From the docs:

> If you want to be notified whenever $digest is called, you can register a watchExpression function with no listener. (Be prepared for multiple calls to your watchExpression because it will execute multiple times in a single $digest cycle if a change is detected.)

[Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)